# Handling large amounts of variants (3 million+) in e-commerce software

Tags: javascript, bigdata, shopping-cart

Boss doesn't believe me when I say 3 million entries per item is a problem. Told me to defer, notify user, and scale some servers.

I have a server side implementation that pulls data from multiple e-commerce integrations, calculate the cartesian product of all of the possible variations of the item, stores them in a cache, then serves them client side where they are heavily looped. This works perfectly for items with less than 200 variants, aka normal items.

Example:

T-Shirt

Size:
Small
Medium
Large

Color:
Red
Blue
Orange

Cartesian variants:
(small, red) (small, blue) (small, orange) (medium, red) ...

We received a client who has items with:

7 option sets

with some option sets having: 50 options each

Now, this customer is not doing anything inherently wrong. They are offering clothing with many color options for individual parts of the item.

Is there a way to handle this in an elegant way? No, right?

Comment: What is going on in the client side looping?

Comment: why are you calculating each possible variant?

Comment: What does "3 million entries per item" mean?  What's an entry?  What's an item?  And, why does every combination have to be precomputed?  Usually, when there are this many variants, you compute a combination on demand and build a reasonable sized cache for the combinations that are actually used.  Precomputing a massive data set where you will only use a tiny percentage of the options in any reasonable time is generally a false economy.   Compute upon demand and if that has performance issues, then work on making that faster.

Comment: FYI, it might be faster to cache the items and compute a variant upon demand rather than cache all the possible variants.  Creating a variant if the items are already in memory should be very fast.

Comment: Before I finish reading the comments I just wanna say this is an awesome question

Comment: This is where [elasticsearch](http://elastic.co) shines.  I had a similar issue when parsing and indexing 16000 documents into the chapters, sub-chapters, sections and many paragraphs, along with metadata.  It's not quite on the same scale you have but the server it ran blazing fast on was a virtual server with 2 cores, 2GB RAM and 48GB disk space.